# Persisting login after refresh

Tags: reactjs, auth0

Login is not persisting in reactjs application. I am using spa reactjs sample. Here is a link https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react. I have to login everytime if I refresh the page. Please suggest what needs to be done to persist login after refresh.

Comment: use local storage to persist login data. `react` or `redux` state is lost on refresh.

Comment: Save your access token in localStorage or sessionStorage

Comment: Thanks for yours comments. I was using social login (e.g. google) and in the documentation I found I have to create oauth credentials (clientId and secret) in google console and need to add those credentials in auth 0 dashboard (Collection > social) menu in Auth0 dashboard.

Comment: Saving your access token in localStorage is not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please follow this official document points. It might help you

**https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login#restoring-login-state-with-social-providers**